# Value of type 'Range' has no member 'map' and ˝Type 'Matrix' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'˝

Tags: swift2, swift3

I am trying to convert [MathSwift](https://github.com/huangenyan/MathSwift) to swift3 and some issues could not resolve as ˝Value of type 'Range' has no member 'map'˝:

```
func toIntArray(index: MatrixIndexType) -> [Int] {

if index is [Int] {
    return index as! [Int]
} else if let rangeIndex = index as? Range<Int> {
    return rangeIndex.map({$0})
} else if let intIndex = index as? Int {
    return [intIndex]
}
return []}
```

More issues appear like ˝Type 'Matrix' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'˝

```
extension Matrix: Sequence {

public func generate() -> AnyIterator<Double> {
    var nextIndex = 0
    return AnyIterator<Double> {
        if nextIndex == self.elements.count {
            return nil
        }
        nextIndex += 1
        return self.elements[nextIndex]
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First issue:**

Replace

```
return rangeIndex.map({$0})
```

with

```
return [Int](rangeIndex.lowerBound..<rangeIndex.upperBound)
```

---

**Second issue:**

Replace

```
public func generate() -> AnyIterator<Double> {
```

with

```
public func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<Double> {
```

---

But the iterator function cannot work because the item at index 0 will never be considered.
To fix that

Replace

```
nextIndex += 1
return self.elements[nextIndex]
```

with

```
let element = self.elements[nextIndex]
nextIndex += 1
return element
```

Comment: The second original item is `return self.elements[nextIndex++]` I changed to first increment before return...

Comment: I suspected that. :-) Post-increment is not possible in Swift 3

Comment: I thought the ideia was return the next item of array... not?

Comment: No, it's get the item **then** increment the index and return the item. What you think is `[++nextIndex]` which is a huge difference in this particular case. By the way your code in the question will crash.